How to Implement OAuth Login Using LinkedIn OpenID Connect
I want to integrated LinkedIn login into one of my apps, and I want a step-by-step guide with code examples on how to do it.
I followed this guide (https://shvbsle.in/linkedin-sign-in-with-nextjs-2024/) and got error
{
status: 403,
serviceErrorCode: 100,
code: 'ACCESS_DENIED',
message: 'Not enough permissions to access: userinfo.GET.NO_VERSION'
}
please help....

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use passportJS
Their docs has the code examples.

I am using Nextjs

@NaveenYadav it can be used with nextjs, give it a try.
